# Yii alias not working in my main.php

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to create a `site` alias in my `frontend/config/main.php` but it doesn't seem to import all the classes from my `common/components/`

here is my file structure

```
backend/
    common/
        components/
            Globals.php
        config/
            params.php
            params-local.php
        lib/
            yii/
        migrations/
        models/
            Comment.php
            Extension.php
            ...
    console/
        commands/
            SitemapCommand.php
            ...
        config/
            main.php
            main-local.php
            params.php
            params-local.php
        runtime/
        yiic.php
    frontend/
        components/
        config/
            main.php
            main-local.php
            params.php
            params-local.php
        controllers/
            SiteController.php
            ...
        lib/
        models/ 
            ContactForm.php
            SearchForm.php      
        runtime/
        views/
            layouts/
            site/
        www/
            assets/
            css/
            js/
            index.php
    yiic
    yiic.bat
```

this is what i have so far

```
$root=dirname(__FILE__).'/../..';

//define a path alias, site
Yii::setPathOfAlias('site',$root);

//merging together our frontend params with our common application params
$params=array_merge(
    require($root.'/common/config/params.php'),
    require($root.'/frontend/config/params.php')
);

return array(
    'name'=>'site name',

    'basePath'=>$root.'/frontend',

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>$params,

    // preloading 'app' component in frontend/extensions
    'preload'=>array('log','app'),

    // auto loading model and component classes from this application and our common application
    'import'=>array(
        'site.common.components.*',
        'site.common.models.*',
        'site.common.extensions.mailer.components.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'application.models.*',
    ),
         .......
);
```

everything using the site alias isn't loaded here. When i call `Globals::isAdmin();` in my footer.php, i get an error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Globals::isAdmin() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/dev/frontend/views/layouts/footer.php on line 81
```

my `$root` is set too

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/dev/frontend/config/../..
```

my Global class looks like this

```
class Globals {

         /* 
          * Check if user is an admin
          */ 
         public static function isAdmin() 
         {
          $testId = Yii::app()->user->id;
          $role = User::model()->findByPk($testId);

          return ($role['role'] == 1) ? true : false;
        }
}
```

Any idea what i'm missing or doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. i had duplicate global classes in my `common.components.` and `frontend.components.` folders. silly me

Answer (score 0):

May be your param merging has some problem because as you set $root and again in your require /frontend/config/params.php

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/dev/frontend/config/../..

$params=array_merge(
require($root.'/common/config/params.php'),
require($root.'/frontend/config/params.php')
);
```